# How to combine broken lines in excel

Tags: string, vba, excel

I have an excel table containing thousands of lines. Some of the lines in the first column are broken. None broken lines always have neighboring columns with data in them. Broken lines don't. In other words, how do I convert the following:

[image]

into this:

[image]

Comment: This looks like a call for a VBA macro to me. Basically, you step through the rows. If you find a row with a value in both columns A and B, set a reference to that row. If you find a row with a value in column A but not column B, take the value in column A, append it to the last recorded reference row's column A, and empty the current column A. Keep doing this until you are done.

Comment: I don't know how to use VBA :(

Comment: Well, give me a moment to write up a simple tutorial. Which version of Excel do you use?

Comment: I use Excel 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code block with the changes you requested. I decided to just replace the whole code block based on (1) the fact that you do not know VBA coding, and (2) the fact that I don't know what, if any, coding you actually know. Complete replacement is easier than editing for someone who doesn't have coding experience.

```
Dim MaxRow As Integer

Sub MergeRows()

Dim Ptr As Integer
Dim I As Integer

Dim WorkStr As String
Dim S As String
Dim Space As String

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Activate    ' Move to the first cell
GetMaxRow                           ' Get the last row in the worksheet
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Activate    ' Move to the first cell

Ptr = 0
I = 0

For I = 1 To MaxRow
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 1).Value > "" Then
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 2).Value > "" Then
            Ptr = I
        Else
            If Ptr > 0 Then
                Space = " "

                WorkStr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Ptr, 1).Value
                S = ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 1).Value

                If Right(WorkStr, 1) = "-" Then
                    WorkStr = Left(WorkStr, Len(WorkStr) - 1)
                    Space = ""
                End If

                If Left(S, 1) = "-" Then
                    S = Right(S, Len(S) - 1)
                    Space = ""
                End If

                ActiveSheet.Cells(Ptr, 1).Value = WorkStr & IIf(Right(WorkStr, 1) = " " Or Left(S, 1) = " ", "", Space) & S

            End If
            ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 1).Value = ""

        End If
    End If
Next I

End Sub

Sub GetMaxRow()
'
    MaxRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

These are the steps you will want to follow. You should make a backup copy of the spreadsheet before you do ANY of this.

- Open your Excel spreadsheet.
- ### Make sure that the sheet you want to work on is the active worksheet

  - This would be a good time to make sure that you have that backup of the original data file.
- Click on File / Options / Customize Ribbon
- In the right-hand list of checkboxes, if the Developer checkbox is not checked, check it
- Click [OK]
- Click on the DEVELOPER tab
- Double Click the Visual Basic icon
- On the window that pops up, Right click on the Microsoft Excel Objects entry under the current workbook name. Then select Insert -> Module from the pop-up menu. It should look something like this:

[image: Inserting a workbook]

- After the workbook is inserted, this tree will look more like this:

[image]

- You will also have a subwindow, probably titled **[workbook name] - Module1 (Code)**. This is where the VBA code will be placed. Copy the code below:

---

```
Dim MaxRow As Integer

Sub MergeRows()

Dim Ptr As Integer
Dim I As Integer

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Activate    ' Move to the first cell
GetMaxRow                           ' Get the last row in the worksheet
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Activate    ' Move to the first cell

Ptr = 0
I = 0

For I = 1 To MaxRow
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 1).Value > "" Then
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 2).Value > "" Then
            Ptr = I
        Else
            If Ptr > 0 Then ActiveSheet.Cells(Ptr, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(Ptr, 1).Value & ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 1).Value

            ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 1).Value = ""

        End If
    End If
Next I

End Sub

Sub GetMaxRow()
'
    MaxRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

End Sub
```

---

- Paste the copied code into the empty Module1 window.
- Click on the line `Dim Ptr As Integer`
- Press F5
- Wait for a few seconds
- Close the module. It is up to you if you want to save the code, but you will probably never need it again in this workbook. Just save the reference to this question... just in case.
- Close the **Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications** window.
- Validate your data.

If there are any problems, update this answer and I'll check it out.

Comment: Nice tutorial material!

Comment: Wow that's great! Can you add two conditions to the code: 1) If the line breaks with hyphen then remove the hyphen and combine them with no space. 2) If the line breaks without the hyphen then combine them with a space.

Answer (score 2):

If we start with:

[image]

and run this short macro:

```
Sub Kompaktor()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, IDidSomething As Boolean
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        IDidSomething = True
        While IDidSomething
            IDidSomething = False
            For i = N To 2 Step -1
                If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" And .CountA(Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 7))) = 0 Then
                    IDidSomething = True
                    Cells(i - 1, 1).Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value & " " & Cells(i, 1).Value
                    Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
                End If
            Next i
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

We will end up with:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[`SpecialCells()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx) could come very handy here:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        For Each cell In .Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(, -1)
            With IIf(IsEmpty(cell.Offset(-1)), cell.End(xlUp), cell.Offset(-1))
                .Value = IIf(Right(.Value, 1) = "-", Left(.Value, Len(.Value) - 1), .Value & " ") & cell.Value
            End With
            cell.ClearContents
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```